# How does Bind IP to MAC work?

Tags: dhcp, arp

A client is connected to the network with a DHCP server, but also has a Bind IP to MAC entry in the router. What is the sequence of steps that determine the final client IP configuration given that (1) the client is configured to obtain IP from DHCP server; (2) the client is configured to use static IP.

**Long Story**

I have an old Cisco Aironet 1242AG to be set up as an (lightweight) access point, it appears that DHCP querying is faulty and it does not get registered in the DHCP server and I cannot get to the configuration page as described in the installation manual. My Draytek Vigor 3900 has a Bind IP to MAC function, but it seems I still cannot get to the access point. Hope to have a better understanding of how "Bind IP to MAC" works.

Comment: The first google result I got was http://www.draytek.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=5486&Itemid=293&lang=en

Comment: I am not asking how to configure it on DrayTek. I am asking a generic question for the sequence of events that happens when the client is connected. Please do not read the long story if it confuses you.

Comment: 'Bind IP to MAC' is specific to Draytek... if you want information on the generic term you would want to look up 'DCHP Reservaton', or start with reading about DHCP in general.  Question (2) is not a real question since a client configured with a static IP address will use the configured address, there are no further steps.

Comment: I'm sorry but it is not specific to draytek. A lot of routers have this function if you can just google. I specifically do not want DHCP reservation. Question (2) is a real question, as if you are right, then the answer would be the client will not query for an IP and other clients will (not) be able to reach it at the bound IP. Please write that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

'Bind IP to MAC' is specific to Draytek... if you want information on the generic term you would want to look up 'DCHP Reservation', or start with reading about DHCP in general. Question (2) is not a real question since a client configured with a static IP address will use the configured address, there are no further steps.

Comment: I have [already](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/547197/Huawei-Ws325.html?page=52) [explained](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/wireless/controller/7-4/configuration/guides/consolidated/b_cg74_CONSOLIDATED/b_cg74_CONSOLIDATED_chapter_01101.html) that binding IP to MAC is not exclusive to DrayTek routers. Care to explain why you insist otherwise before making a sweeping statement?

Comment: 'Binding IP to MAC' in the Draytek definition of the term is very specific to Draytek and they are talking about 'DHCP Reservations'.  Other vendors using the words 'bind', 'IP' and 'mac' in the same sentence are performing some kind of arp-spoofing defense.  Since you have the links, please read them and the Draytek link to determine the difference.

Comment: If you read carefully the DrayTek documentation you will know that it is not about DHCP reservation, but instead it is to do with ARP just like other vendors. I do not understand what makes you think DrayTek is any different from other vendors that you keep wanting to go back to vendor specific discussion. Anyway, I will rest my case. Thanks.

Comment: The Draytek documentation literally says `What is Bind IP to MAC?

     While DHCP sever dynamically assign a IP address every time a device connects to the network, Bind IP to MAC could avoid IP address changing with reconnection. Once a specified IP address and a device's MAC address are bound, the IP address will be reserved for the device and the device will get that IP address every time it connects to the router.` How is this not DHCP reservation?